# Rearranging a matrix by the greatest values of the rows

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a function that accepts four vectors. The Function "stacks" the vectors on each other to create a matrix with 4 rows. The matrix has to be rearranged so that the row with the biggest number will be in the top. Then, finding the greatest number in the three bottom lines, and place the line that contains it in under the top. Then, looking for the largest number two bottom lines and place the line that contains the third place from the top.
Function returns the matrix obtained.

For example :

```
v1=[1 2 3 4] v2=[5 6 7 8] v3=[9 10 11 12] v4=[13 14 15 16];
```

the output should be

```
m=[13 14 15 16;
    9 10 11 12;
       5 6 7 8; 
       1 2 3 4]
```

that what I have done for now, but it doesn't work properly

```
function [ x ] = re( v1,v2,v3,v4 )

vec=[v1;v2;v3;v4];
[r,y]=size(vec);
h=[];
e=[];
l=[];
p=[];

a=sort(v1,'descend');
b=sort(v2,'descend');
c=sort(v3,'descend');
d=sort(v4,'descend');

elVector=[a(1),b(1),c(1),d(1)];

sortIt=sort(elVector,'descend');

for i=a:d
for j=1:r
if sortIt(1)==i(1)
  h=vec(j,1:y);

for ii=a:d
for jj=1:r
  if sortIt(2)==ii(1)
  e=vec(jj,1:y);

for iii=a:d
for jjj=1:r
  if sortIt(3)==iii(1)
  l=vec(jjj,1:y);

for iiii=a:d
for jjjj=1:r
  if sortIt(4)==iiii(1)
  p=vec(jjjj,1:y);


  end
end
end
  end
end
end
  end
end
end
end
end
end

x=[h;e;l;p];  
end`
```

### EDIT: regarding matrix example in the comment

the matrix should look like this at the end:

x =

```
 0     0    10     0
 0     4     0     0
 0     0     0     2
 0     0     1     0
```

so the vector with the greatest value at the top and next greatest value in the second row..(10,4,2,1).

and now it works after i fixed the code that I wrote previously:

>

```
 function [ x ] = re( v1,v2,v3,v4 )

vec=[v1;v2;v3;v4];
[r,y]=size(vec);
h=[];
e=[];
l=[];
p=[];

a=sort(vec(1,1:y),'descend');
b=sort(vec(2,1:y),'descend');
c=sort(vec(3,1:y),'descend');
d=sort(vec(4,1:y),'descend');

elVector=[a(1),b(1),c(1),d(1)];
sortIt=sort(elVector,'descend');

for i=1:length(elVector)

      if (sortIt(1))==elVector(i)
      h=vec(i,1:y);

      end

      if (sortIt(2))==elVector(i)
      e=vec(i,1:y);
      end

      if (sortIt(3))==elVector(i)
      l=vec(i,1:y);
      end

      if (sortIt(4))==elVector(i)
      p=vec(i,1:y);

      end
end

x=[h;e;l;p]; 
end
```

but still I would like to know if there is a function in matlab does this.
thank you for the help/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)... so no need for nested loops and multiple sorts, for example

```
A=[v1;v2;v3;v4]
B = flipud(sortrows(A))

B =
    13    14    15    16
     9    10    11    12
     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4
```

**EDIT:**

What you want can be done using:

```
[~, IX]=sort(max(A')','descend')
```

then

```
A(IX,:)

A(IX,:) =
     0     0    10     0
     0     4     0     0
     0     0     0     2
     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: why the flipud(sortrows(A)) doesnt work on this matrix: w =

     0     0     1     0
     0     0    10     0
     0     0     0     2
     0     4     0     0

Comment: `w = [0 0 1 0; 0 0 10 0; 0 0 0 2; 0 4 0 0];` `flipud(sortrows(w))` probably doesn't work because you actually wanted to sort the columns, not the rows ()despite what the title of the question says) -the example matrix you gave makes it hard to tell which. Try `sort(w,'descend')`.